# Weird Issue with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I'm building a multi-module elastic beanstalk environment with three components.  I ran

```
eb init --modules mod1 mod2 mod3
```

without incident. The tool asked me to confirm that one was Docker, one Node, and one Python. However, when I run

```
eb create  --modules mod1 mod2 mod3 --env-group-suffix dev
```

aws says

```
WARNING: The module mod1 does not contain an env.yaml file. This module will be skipped.
WARNING: The module mod2 does not contain an env.yaml file. This module will be skipped.
WARNING: The module mod3 does not contain an env.yaml file. This module will be skipped.
```

Each directory has an env.yml so I don't know what the issue is. Is this one of those poorly-written AWS errors?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was happening. I deleted all AWS artifacts (e.g. .elasticbeanstalk) and went through the creation process again and the issue went away. I must have had some outdates file from a previous attempt.

Possible answer: the branch-defaults in config.yml had a weird value. That might have been the issue.